# ESP32 + ST7735S display circuit diagram

Tags: circuit-design, esp32, display

Is the circuit diagram correct? I am not sure about the connections marked in purple. I am still entry level at this.

[image: circuit-diagram]

Edit: The purpose of this circuit is to be powered from a Li-Ion Battery. Vbat is also run though an LDO regulator to give 3.3v to the ESP32. The display can accept 3.3-5V. J1 is to program the ESP32. When this happens the screen needs to be reset otherwise be on. CS as I understand it will determine if data will go to the ESP32 or display. I have done no physical testing so far because I am scared I will blow it up. My concerns are that LCD_RST will not make the screen come on and LCD_CS might not be the correct place so select between display and programmer. I am not sure If I can connect the Led Kathode to the same ground as the display ground and if this will cause it to either not work or break. The closest thing to a datasheet I can find is at the bottom of the product page of the display https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/JMD-0-96-inch-13P-HD_60813913717.html?spm=a2700.shop_plgr.41413.11.34a34d4cX6kusR  My endgoal is to press the button and that some text must display.

Comment: Welcome - Please [edit] your question & add the link to that specific display's datasheet (at least one of the points you raise can vary between displays even with the same LCD controller). Also please explain the difference between Vbat (used for the LCD backlight) and VCC on the schematic, as well as how you have confirmed that Vbat is suitable for that specific display. Finally (for me - others may have additional questions) what testing / prototyping / etc. have you done already & with what results? Do you have *specific* concerns about those marked signals? If so, why? Context helps. TY

Comment: Thanks. I made an edit and tried to give as much information as I possibly can based on your suggestion.

Comment: @SamGibson, sorry I didn't know I had to @ you. I added alot more info and context as you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I soldered small wires to the module and connected them to a breadboard then tested the uart programming using the Arduino IDE and output a serial message once booted. Once the module is powered it automatically enters boot mode and starts flashing the firmware. No button presses are required during the build compile and flash stages. Once flashing completes the module reset is triggered and the message is displayed on the serial monitor. I managed to read the model number from the screens and was able to get the datasheet as I could not manage to hand solder them without shorting pins so my next answer is based on what I read and assume from the datasheet. LCD_RS and LCD_RST connected to the screen would function in a similar way turning it off during flashing and coming on once reset. Vbat(3.7V Li-Ion) connected to the lcd is also fine and connecting K to ground I can only confirm once I manage to get one soldered correctly but I am assuming it should be fine as the datasheet does not specifically state one is needed.